# Running Logstash from Java project?

Tags: logstash

Is it possible to run Logstash from Java project, 
Currently I'm trying to add into this project new module (Maven based) with a Logstash (v1.4.2). In fact I want to bundle a Logstash and prepare some servlet which will be able to start Logstash process. At the beginning I thought it will be easy, because Logstash is written in JRuby. Unfortunately, I have a problem with it and maybe someone could help with idea how to achieve that.

Comment: What's the problem and what do you want to achieve? Logstash is normally run as a daemon and I'm not sure it makes sense to run it from your program. Still, it should be possible just like it's possible to run any other process.

Comment: Hi Mr @MagnusBäck, you seem really like my supervisor and I like it, it's too nice to be surrounded by genius people who help me, I think you have now a good idea of my project, and to recap, I will collect data from log firewall with logstash, and treat it with ElasticSearch and display it  with Kibana,
well then I think it's better to connect t the three tools to both with java for example? 

Ah ? what do you think ? Any other idea ?

Comment: I don't see the point of using a Java program here. There might be corner cases where it's a good idea but until you know this better I suggest you stick to a standard setup.